# PartialView is not showing in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an array which as the number(**Id's of some tags**) and I am passing this array to the action method using ajax call when this array passed to the controller action method(**RawTagCreation**) and then the numbers in this arrays are used to get data from database and then pass to another ViewModel object  (`rawTagVMs`) and then I am returning the partial view with this ViewModel object. The problem is that the partial view is not showing?
Basically success event of ajax call is also not fired.

```
function selectedValues() {
            var datas = [];
            $('#search_to option').each(function () {
                datas.push($(this).attr('value'));
            });
            console.log(datas);
            if (datas.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("RawTagCreation", "SourceTagMapping")",
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'selectedTags': datas }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('Please Select One or More Raw Tags')
            }
        }
```

The action method is given here

```
 public ActionResult RawTagCreation(int[] selectedTags)
        {
            List<RawTagVM> rawTagVMs = new List<RawTagVM>();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var item in selectedTags)
                {

                    var OldSourecTag = db.Real_Raw_Points.Where(x => x.Source_Tag_Id_Fk == item).FirstOrDefault();
                    var OPCTag = db.OPC_SourceTags.Where(x => x.Source_Tag_Id == item).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (OldSourecTag == null)
                    {
                        RawTagVM objToInsertRawTags = new RawTagVM();
                        objToInsertRawTags.Source_Tag_Id_Fk = item;
                        objToInsertRawTags.R_Tag_Name = "Provide Tag Name";
                        rawTagVMs.Add(objToInsertRawTags);

                    }
                }
                return PartialView("_Update_TagNames", rawTagVMs);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

PartialView is here

```
@model List<OmniConnect.ViewModel.RawTagViews.RawTagVM>
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update The Raw Tag Names</h3>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>


<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Confirm()">Confirm Update</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the action and see what happens.

Comment: Put an error on the ajax call and print out all the information given in the errors.

Comment: @Neil can you tell me how I can print the error in error event?

Comment: @nado1122 It looks like you are getting the debugger on your method? but while returning you are not getting any call. Can you try removing contentType: 'application/json' from the ajax call. and add error: function(xhr, status,p3,p4) and let me know your observaations.

Answer (score 0):

when you try ajax call
you can't return partial view

if you want return a view you must use form like Html.Beginform
and submit

if you want return success method you must return a value may be string 
and append it to a tag

```
 public ActionResult RawTagCreation(int[] selectedTags)
    {
        List<RawTagVM> rawTagVMs = new List<RawTagVM>();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return Json("<div>any view</div");
        }
        return json("");
    }
```

and then you can use like this:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("RawTagCreation", "SourceTagMapping")",
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'selectedTags': datas }),
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
```